# how do I solve the following differntial equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

1.$(D^2+3D+2)y=e^{2x}8x$
and

2. $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-4x\frac{dy}{dx}+(4x^2-1)y=-3^{x^2}8*2x$

I am not getting any idea how to begin solving these problems

Comment: In the first equation what is $D$ and $M$? and in the second what is $M$?

Comment: I also don't know what it is .It's just given in the question

Comment: What tools do you have at your disposal?  These equations can be solved a number of ways.  Have you learned about the Laplace Transform yet?

Comment: I'd assume that D is a standard way of denoting a differential operator

Comment: @Dr.MV I don't know about laplace transform but you can solve it in whichever way find it simple to explain.You can also use laplace transform

Comment: In the second equation, is there a $y$ missing from the $4x^2-1$ term?

Comment: @Dr.MV ya it was now I edited it .Sorry for that mistake

Comment: Use curly brackets to contain multiple objects in a superscript like with exponentials like e^{2x}

Comment: Have you done the not so frequently taught inverse operator method?

Comment: @Triatticus No I have not done that .But you can explain your solution using that

Comment: anyone got the solution?

Comment: A problem is still not knowing what M is, did this come from a book? A professor? An online source? It would be helpful if we were given more information

Comment: from the professor

Comment: @Dr.MV can you help?

Comment: I assume that $D$ is the operator $\frac{d}{dx}$.  But is $M$ an operator, a general function of $x$, or simply a constant?

Comment: @Dr.MV  what if I  there were no M could you solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the very first things one learns in a "Differential Equations" course, is to use the "characteristic equation" to find solutions to a "linear differential equation with constant coefficients" which this is.

$(D^2+ 3D+ 2)y= e^{2x}8x$ is just such a differential equation with characteristic equation $r^2+ 3r+ 2= (r+ 2)(r+ 1)= 0$ which has solutions r= -1 and r= -2.  The general solution to the "associated homogeneous equation", $(D^2+ 3D+ 2)y= 0$, is $y(x)= Ae^{-x}+ Be^{-2x}$ for A and B any constants.  Since the "non-homogeneous" part, the right side, $e^{2x}8x$ **is** of the form we would expect for a solution for this kind of equation, we can **try** a solution, to the entire equation, of the form $y= e^{2x}(Ax+ B)$ (this is called "undetermined coefficients").  With $y= e^{2x}(Ax+ B)$, $Dy= 2e^{2x}(Ax+ B)+ e^{2x}(A)= 2e^{2x}(Ax+ A+ B)$ and $y''= 4e^{2x}(Ax+ A+ B)+ 2e^{2x}(A)= 2e^{2x}(2Ax+ 3A+ 2B)$.

Putting that into the differential equation, $D^2y+ 3Dy+ 2y= 2e^{2x}(2Ax+ 3A+ 2B)+ 6e^{2x}(Ax+ A+ B)+ 2e^{2x}(Ax+ B)= e^{2x}(4Ax+ 6A+ 4B+ 6Ax+ 6B+ 2Ax+ 2B)= e^{2x}(12Ax+ 8A+ 12B)= e^{2x}(8x+ 0)$ so we must have 12A= 8 and 8A+ 12B= 0.  A= 8/12= 2/3 so 8(2/3)+ 12B= 0.  12B= -16/3, B= -2/9.

The general solution the entire equation is $y(x)= Ae^{-x}+ Be^{-2x}+ e^{2x}((2/3)x- 2/9$

If you did not know how to solve that first equation, I can't imagine how you would solve that second equation- it looks like a version of "Bessel's equation" whose solutions are "Bessel's functions" that cannot be written in term of "elementary functions".